# How to run a Django project on Ubuntu in AWS EC2?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I have created a Django application and uploaded in to AWS EC2. I can access the site using public IP address only when I run the `python manage.py` in AWS command line.

If I close the Putty window, I am not able to access the site. How can I make sure that the site is available always even if I close the command line / putty?

I tried WSGI option but its not working at all. Appreciate your help to give us a solution to run the Python application in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are running the app from within the SSH session, which means that ending the session (SIGHUP) will kill your application.

There are several ways to keep the app running after you disconnect the SSH, the simplest would be to run it inside a `screen` session and keeping this instance running while disconnecting from SSH, the advantage of this method is that you can still control the app when you are reconnecting to this machine and control the state of the app and also potentially see the logs.

Although it might be pretty cool it's considered a patch, the more stable and solid way would be to create a service that will run the app and will allow you to start, stop and look at logs using the nifty wrappers of `systemd`.

Keep the process running with screen:

- First you'll have to make sure screen is installed (`apt-get` or `yum`) whatever suits your desired distro.
- Run `screen`.
- Run the app just like you did outside screen.
- Detach from the screen session by pressing `Ctrl+A` and then `d`.
- Disconnect from the SSH and see how the service is still running.

Creating a `systemd` service is a bit more complicated so try and read through the [following manual](https://vsupalov.com/django-systemd-crashcourse/).